# How to set character encoding in header in a NextJS app?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

NextJS, by default, serves a page with the charset information in a meta tag like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" class="next-head">
```

However, I am looking to serve this data embedded with the page header as:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I have a custom Express server where I define port and other middleware for NextJS. In this file (server.js), I have tried the following; it runs without error but does not do anything to the header:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.charset = 'utf8',
      handle(req, res)
 });
```

Any expert opinion would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

set response content type like this:

```
res.set({ 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' })
```

however the default charset is utf8, you don't need to override it.